# Valid_from Valid_to from a full loaded table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, gaps-and-islands

There is a source table which loads the data full and monthly. The table looks like below example.

Source table:

| pk | code_paym | code_terms | etl_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2020-08-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2020-09-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2020-10-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2020-11-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2020-12-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-04-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-05-01 |

I would like to create valid_from valid_to columns from the source table like below example.

Desired Output:

| pk | code_paym | code_terms | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2020-08-01 | 2020-09-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2020-10-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-05-01 |

As it can be seen attributes can go back to the same values by the time.
How can I make this output happen by sql code?

Thank you very much,
Regards

Comment: Please provide text instead of images and tag the question with the type of database you are using.

Comment: @ggordon thanks for the correction! I have just updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event.html) windowed function to determine continuous subgroups:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t( pk INT,  code_paym INT,  code_terms INT,     etl_id DATE)
AS
          SELECT 1,     2,  3,  '2020-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  3,  '2020-09-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  4,  '2020-10-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  4,  '2020-11-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  4,  '2020-12-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  4,  '2021-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  3,  '2021-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  3,  '2021-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  3,  '2021-04-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,     2,  3,  '2021-05-01';
```

Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.*, 
    CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(CODE_TERMS != LAG(CODE_TERMS,1,CODE_TERMS)
                                   OVER(PARTITION BY PK, CODE_PAYM ORDER BY ETL_ID)) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY PK, CODE_PAYM ORDER BY ETL_ID) AS grp 
  FROM t 
)
SELECT PK, CODE_PAYM, grp, MIN(ETL_ID) AS valid_from, MAX(ETL_ID) AS valid_to
FROM cte
GROUP BY PK, CODE_PAYM, grp;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Lukasz Szozda, Thank you very much for your help. This is very useful for me. I really apreciated with your answer. Only one thing I am crious about that if cod_paym was also variable, how would you write the code?

Comment: If I understood correctly, only PK has to be partitioned then: `WITH cte AS (   SELECT t.*,      CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(CONCAT(CODE_TERMS, ';',CODE_PAYM) != CONCAT(LAG(CODE_TERMS,1,CODE_TERMS)                                    OVER(PARTITION BY PK  ORDER BY ETL_ID))             ,';'    ,LAG(CODE_PAYM,1,CODE_PAYM)                                    OVER(PARTITION BY PK  ORDER BY ETL_ID)            )                OVER(PARTITION BY PK ORDER BY ETL_ID) AS grp    FROM t  ) SELECT PK, grp, MIN(ETL_ID) AS valid_from, MAX(ETL_ID) AS valid_to FROM cte GROUP BY PK, grp;`

Comment: @dwh_dev Great to hear that :) [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)